# Разнотипные списки python

Tags: python, list, коллекции

Есть параметр типа строка

```
string = 'value'
```

Так же есть параметр типа словарь

```
dic = {"value": "value11"}
```

Задача закинуть эти параметры в список\массив, получив

```
list = [string, dic]
```

есть поддержка разнотипных элементов списка\массива?

Comment: `list` это встроенное в Питон имя, избегайте его использование для своих переменных.

Comment: Что мешало проверить в интерпретаторе?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string = 'value'
dic = {"value": "value11"}

lst = [string, dic]
print(lst)  # ['value', {'value': 'value11'}]

# Или:
lst = []
lst.append(string)
lst.append(dic)
print(lst)  # ['value', {'value': 'value11'}]
```

Answer (score 3):

В лист можно закидывать всё что угодно.
 Это не должен быть обязательно лист строк или лист диктов, все что угодно.
 Что-бы добавить элемент в лист, делайте так:

```
list = []  
list.append(string) 
list.append(dic)
list.append(my_number)
list.append(anything_else)
```